# WordCloud 'module' object is not callable Python3

Tags: python-3.x, object, word-cloud

Ok, so I'm trying to extract text from a pdf and display a wordcloud from the extractedText.

Recieving TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
at line

`cloud = wordcloud(mask=rsMask).generate(pageObj.extractText())`

Here's the code I'm running, thanks in advance, cheers:

```
 #Extracting text from a pdf

import wordcloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import PyPDF4


pdfFileObj = open('Test-Resume-Doc.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pageText = (pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()

rsMask = np.array(Image.open('Resume_WordCloud.png'))
print(rsMask)
#
cloud = wordcloud(mask=rsMask).generate(pageObj.extractText())
print(cloud)

plt.imshow(cloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You call `imshow` function from `plt` module as `plt.imshow` and `array` function from `np` module, both correctly. You have to do the same with a function from the `wordcloud` module: `wordcloud.somefunction(mask=rsMask).generate...`

Comment: Thanks so much!! Problem solved. changed to : `cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud(mask = rsMask).generate(pageObj.extractText())`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with the code that module is mixed with class that is defined in a module. Please try this:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
cloud = WordCloud(mask=rsMask).generate(pageObj.extractText())
```

The cloud will be an image so you cannot print it to console, you will have to display it somewhere(or write to file).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @DaruiszOstolski and @mkiever here is the completed solution for those who encounter a similar issue with stopwords added:

```
#Exracting text from a pdf

#import libraries
import wordcloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import PyPDF4

#open pdf extract text
pdfFileObj = open('docName.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
pageText = (pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()

#create array with extracted text
rsMask = np.array(Image.open('pngName.png'))

#create cloud from wordcloud.WordCloud with stopwords bcg color mask generated cloud
cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud(stopwords='stopwords.txt', background_color="black", mask=rsMask).generate(pageObj.extractText())

#display and save
plt.imshow(cloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig('.../path...newPNGName.png'.format(cloud))
plt.show()
```